# SOQL query for fetching records created when same customer calls the same Representative on same day

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, soql

I'm trying to fetch records that were created when same customer calls the same customer representative on the same day - to identify duplicate records. considering that recently created case that day by same customer service representative when called by the same customer is the most updated and original.

I would really appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good start

```
SELECT AccountId, CreatedById, DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate), COUNT(Id), MAX(Id)
FROM Case
GROUP BY AccountId, CreatedById, DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate)
HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(Id) DESC, DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) DESC
LIMIT 200
```

You'll have to tweak it to your business spec; maybe use `ContactId` for customer, maybe `OwnerId` for the support rep (but think about Queues too)... something along these lines.

[SOQL HAVING spec](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_having.htm), [DAY_ONLY() trick](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm)